# Why do I get You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

We have two AL sheets, local and national.  I'm trying to get it so that when our local AL "calendar" is completed the data is copied across to the national calendar.  The edited cell is checked if it is in the row of someone that is also on the national, then copied into their respective row on the national spreadsheet.  I keep getting the

> You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openByID.

```
function onEdit(e) {

var range = e.range

var rowNum = range.getRow()
var colNum = range.getColumn()
var sheetEdit = range.getSheet().getName()
var rowEdit = parseInt(rowNum)
var colEdit = parseInt(colNum)
Logger.log(rowEdit)
Logger.log(colEdit)
Logger.log(sheetEdit)

var locSheet = "ID_Local_AL"
var natSheet = "ID_National_AL" //test
var copyEdit = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetEdit).getRange(rowEdit, colEdit, 1, 1).getValue()

//national Rows
var rhRowSMT = SpreadsheetApp.openById(natSheet).getSheetByName(sheetEdit).getCell(12,colEdit)
var jpRowSMT = SpreadsheetApp.openById(natSheet).getSheetByName(sheetEdit).getCell(13,colEdit)
var sahRowSMT = SpreadsheetApp.openById(natSheet).getSheetByName(sheetEdit).getCell(14,colEdit)
var hlRowSMT = SpreadsheetApp.openById(natSheet).getSheetByName(sheetEdit).getCell(15,colEdit)


if (rowEdit = 10) {
  rhRowSMT.setValue(copyEdit)

}

else if (rowEdit = 11) {
  jpRowSMT.setValue(copyEdit)

}

else if (rowEdit = 12) {
  sahRowSMT.setValue(copyEdit)

}

else if (rowEdit = 13) {
  hlRowSMT.setValue(copyEdit)

}

}
```

In theory, if one of the team puts in AL the cell will be checked if they're to be copied over, it copies the contents of that cell into the same date on the National sheet.

Instead I get

> You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`
> at onEdit(Code:28)

I understand that it's because they're two different spreadsheets, but is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue:

Insufficient permissions to call `SpreadsheetApp.openById()`.

---

#### Reason:

The script is running as a [Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/), which run with `authMode = LIMITED`.

---

#### Solution:

Set up an [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) for this instead, so that it runs with `authMode = FULL`.

I'd recommend changing the name of the script, for example:

```
function syncSheets(e) {
```

Then running the following script (adapted from [Google's example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically)) to set up your new Installable Trigger:

```
/**
 * Creates a trigger for when a spreadsheet is edited.
 */
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('syncSheets')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}
```

---

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Event Objects (has `authMode` details)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Managing Triggers Programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically)

Comment: Thanks Ross, that's fixed it.  Well, there were a few errors in the code that I needed to sort once it was running but otherwise fixed!